# Web scraping hidden element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a hidden element (the date) on a website with BeautifulSoup. However, I keep getting a None type or this output: `<span class="hidden-lists">-</span>`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**This is how the relevant part looks on the website:**

```
 <div class="by C C4">
      <span class="hidden-lists">Oct 8, 2018</span>
```

**This is the relevant portion of my code:**

```
 target_3 = page_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "hidden-lists"})
 print(target_3)
```

Comment: might want to include the website url. As with the way you have it above, works fine

Comment: what is the output you're looking for? just the span that contains that date or the contents of the parent div?

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong output"? what is the "wrong" output, and what would the "correct" output be? please explain

Comment: this is the "wrong output" i get: - <span class="hidden-lists">-</span> (I need to extract the date - in this example October 8)

Comment: Have you tried [`target_3.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)?

Comment: Got it. Now Include that in your original question by editing it. In your questions, always try to provide as much info as you can. We obviously dont know what your thinking is a wrong or desired output, so by Including the output you’re getting (the “wrong” output), and the desired output, we get a better idea of the overall goal that you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for that! Just updated my question

Comment: will try that! @MatthewLDaniel

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
target_3.text.strip()
print(target_3)
```

I'm not sure if this will entirely solve your problem, but give it a go.